# CALLBACK function:- How to implement CALLBACK function in javascript for the following functions in phonegap + jQuery mobile iPhone application

Tags: javascript, iphone, jquery-mobile, callback, jquery-callback

I have implemented an **iPhone** application using **jQuery** and **phone gap**..

I was very new to ***`java script`***, ***`jQuery mobile`*** and ***`PhoneGap`***

To retrieve data from the data base tables (table1 and table2 for now still there are 15 tabels exists) *`i have implemented functions in`* `a` **js file** *`as follows`*.

Now i need to implement ***`call back function`*** for these functions

***`How to implement`*** ***call back function*** ***`for the following code for multiple number of tables,Queries and results`***

Comment: Welcome on SO :) As we can see you've successfully found the formatting options :D I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do as there are already callbacks implemented in the getTableX-functions...

Comment: Why did you remove your source code from the question?